# Unicode characters not supported in a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

I am using C# in Visual Studio and I am trying to insert some data into a SQL database.
Some unicode characters are turned into question marks when I try to insert them into the db.
They appear just fine in the code or in a MessageBox.

For example:  `ș Ș ț Ț Ă ă Î î` are turned to `? ? ? ? A a Î î`    //romanian characters

Here is the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bookshelf]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    [Text] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

And here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Comsa\source\repos\Program\Program\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string value = "ș Ș ț Ț Ă ă Î î";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Bookshelf(Text) VALUES('" + value + "')",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

And this is the output:

[image: values in the table]

My question is what UTF does a SQL database use and if there is a way to insert those characters without altering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send Unicode strings prefix the string with `N`:

```
N'This is Unicode'
```

without the prefix it will be treated by whatever 8bit encoding applies.

Also, using string concatenation to build SQL is a recipe for SQL Injection.